# Endless Runner reposition player for equal difficulty regardless of aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating and endless runner for iphones in landscape mode using SpriteKit. I set up the scene as such:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 812, height: 375))
    let skView = view as! SKView
    scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    print("Screen Size: \(GlobalProperties.screenSize.width) x \(GlobalProperties.screenSize.height)")
    print("Scene Size: \(scene.size.width) x \(scene.size.height)")


}
```

I would like to position the player so that there is the same amount of pixels between the edge of the player and the right edge of the screen regardless of aspect ratio. Is this a reasonable practice for maintaining difficulty between devices? I have the layout setup as such:

```
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let player = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "CuteMelon"))
    player.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    player.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width - 600, y: frame.midY)
    self.addChild(player)

    let rect = SKSpriteNode(color: .orange, size: CGSize(width: 550, height: 200))
    rect.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    rect.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width-50, y: frame.height/2)
    self.addChild(rect)
}
```

I added the rectangle to see if in both cases the player was 600 pixels from the right (leaving a 50px gap to ensure it wasnt running off the edge)

The result is as follows:

iPhone XR: https://imgur.com/y6OYHkK which is working as intended

iPhone 8: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQTrM.jpg which is not placing the rectangle 50 pixels from the right bound of the frame.

What do I have to do to fix this issue or should I go about solving it a different way entirely? Thank you

Comment: if you program for the widest device (iphone X) you wont have to worry about what is visible because cropping will happen from top and bottom.  Of course  I would recommend just making a square scene,  then you would never encounter this problem with any future devices.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon but that is not happening, if you look at the images you can see on the iphone 8 it is cropping off of the sides of the background

Comment: Because of your scene size  does not take into account the height of the other devices, so your aspect fill is stretching your scene by height, not by width

Comment: Your height is 200, but you need a height of 309.75 to fit a 9:16 scene.  412.5 for ipads.... hell iphone x needs to be 253.84 so even that is wrong

Comment: Build your scene as a square of 500,500, but make your main visible area a height of 250.  Everything outside of this height is extra drawing fluff, to account for different aspect ratios

Comment: The rectangle isn’t supposed to cover the whole screen vertically. The background image is 812x375 which properly fits the iphoneX. The point is I want the rectangle’s edge to be directly at the edge of the screen and for it to be a set amount if pixels wide. I do not want the top and bottom to be additional background as I would like the full height of the phone to be a playable area @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Then you are going to have to determine the device aspect ratio and shift the camera based on the difference from your 19.5 width.  This of course gives you a problem on iPads since they are only 12x9.  So for iphone which is 16:9, you would have to shift the camera right (3.5/2)* scene width, for ipad, (7.5/2)*scene width

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you for the help I’ll experiment with cameras tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply figure out the difference between the scene size and the screen size, and shift the camera over by half that distance. The formula `abs((sceneWidth - screenWidth * sceneHeight/screenHeight)/2)` will get you that. What this does is scale the screen to whatever height the scene is, then subtract the two differences from the width and return half that value.

```
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let widthPadding = abs((self.frame.width - (UIScreen.main.bounds.width *  self.frame.height / UIScreen.main.bounds.height )) / 2)
    self.camera = self.camera ?? SKCameraNode()

    self.camera.position.x += widthPadding

    let player = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "CuteMelon"))
    player.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    player.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width - 600, y: frame.midY)
    self.addChild(player)

    let rect = SKSpriteNode(color: .orange, size: CGSize(width: 550, height: 200))
    rect.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    rect.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width-50, y: frame.height/2)
    self.addChild(rect)
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed thank you, I totally forgot I had to divide the difference by 2 as the cropping is even on both ends. You have saved me a lot of frustration have a great day!!